# Spring boot executable jar on openshift

Tags: java, spring, openshift, redhat

Here's my start action hook.

```
#helloworld
#!/bin/bash
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
mvn package -s $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/settings.xml -DskipTests=true -U
nohup java -jar target/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} &
```

Once the build is finished. I'm expecting it to run the jar that I have specified. but to my surprise this is the result.

It did not display any status if the application launch, or the banner that I have inside my application.

Here's the result

```
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ friflow-api ---
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 23.261s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 02 23:29:17 EDT 2015
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 25M/316M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

It did not display any error logs. whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting it back here to those who had the same problem as I did. Things you should look out for.

1. Make sure you've correctly configured Maven path

In my case, I just forgot to see the log.